# Is it OK to call a regular JavaScript function within jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it correct to call a regular JavaScript function in a jQuery script or should it be external (it will only be access/used by the jQuery script)? I know that it works but I want to make sure that I am using best practice. For example:

```
$(function(){

    $('.click1').click(function(){
         dofunction();
    }

    $('.click2').click(function(){
         dofunction();
    }

    function testing(grid_array){
         alert('function works!');  
    }

});
```

Comment: jQuery **is** JavaScript. Is it ok to have a JavaScript function inside a JavaScript function? Yes!

Comment: You're creating a closure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

jQuery is a JavaScript library adding facilities, most of them helping to deal with the DOM, AJAX, or crossbrowser issues. Your jQuery script is thus also a JavaScript one.

It's perfectly normal, recommended and fine to call non jQuery based functions from code made using jQuery. In fact, you could hardly avoid that.

Related: [What is the difference between jQuery and JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2490590/what-is-the-difference-between-jquery-and-javascript)

Comment: I love it when you're pretentious and answer as community wiki because your 'moral code' stops you from "accepting the rep" :P

Comment: @user2056238 jQuery is a _library_ built in _javascript_. You're asking if it's ok calling a function from another function in JavaScript? Then yes, it is.